# A question about « Une chose réussit à qn. » and « Qn réussit à une action, une enterprise. »

Tags: verbes, constructions

[image]
[*Please click here to go to Larousse from where this screenshot was taken.*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9ussir/69037)

I’m aware that « Le livre réussit à **qn**. » =
« Le livre procure à qn un avantage. »

**(Q1)** I would like to know if **qch** can replace **qn**. That is, does « Le livre réussit à **qch**. » = « Le livre procure à qch un avantage. »?

For example, does « Le livre réussit à la bibliothèque. » = « Le livre procure à la bibliothèque un avantage. »?

---

[image]
[*Please click here to go to Larousse from where this screenshot was taken.*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9ussir/69037)

I’m aware that « **Qn** réussit à une action, ent**re**prise. » = “Sb is succeeding in an action, an enterprise.”

By “enterprise” I mean *“ a project or undertaking, especially a bold or complex one.”* (<— the definition from *Oxford Languages*)

**(Q2)** I would like to know if **Qch** can replace **Qn**. That is, does « **Qch** réussit à une action, une ent**re**prise. » = “Sth is succeeding in an action, an enterprise.”?

For example, does « Le compilateur a réussit à la compilation du code. » = “The compiler succeeded in the compilation of the code.”?

---

**All I require are yes or no answers.** Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Yes or no only answers are not encouraged, or even allowed in StackExchange. Note also that "Quelqu'un réussit à une action" is quite dubious.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know @jlliagre !  I do come into contact with questions where I need confirmation so I’m guessing questions where I’m asking for confirmation are off limit here also? Also, I have two opposing answers below me thus please could I get your answer.  It would really help me out! 

Comment: It's hard to sort out. Your should first fix Q2 which has a wrong postulate. *Quelqu'un réussit à une action* is just incorrect. You can say *quelqu'un réussit à son premier essai*, *il réussit à son examen* but that's almost it. This is far from being a generic expression.

Comment: @jlliagre I don’t know what a postulate is but I saw that I missed something out and added it in.

Comment: A postulate is something assumed to be true and that is not questioned. The fact is that sentence doesn't work and you didn't remove or replace it. The issue is with the extra preposition **à**.

Comment: @jlliagre But according to the given definition, the sentence does work. :/

Comment: Sentences work when native people find them idiomatic and do not work when native people ears are hurt. *Réussir **à** + noun* existed in the past but almost only survives with *examen*, *essai* and the likes.

Comment: Hm... Thank you for this @jlliagre ! Would it be possible for  you to provide proof of your claim please?

Comment: Here is some kind of a proof "réussir à une action" is not a thing: [Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=r%C3%A9ussit+%C3%A0+une+action%2Cr%C3%A9ussit+une+action&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9ussit%20une%20action%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I understand @ZéhontéeBonteuse Hmm... Maybe *“to be beneficial”* was wrong which is why I made the modification. :) However, I would like to say that in the link in your response it states **« réussir à qn »** = *“to agree with sb, **to do sb good**”*. And **“to do sb good”** = **“to benefit sb”**.

Comment: @jlliagre Is this link showing the frequency on the phrase « réussir à une action » ?

Comment: Which is exactly zero.

Comment: @jlliagre But I’m not looking for the frequency of the phrase « réussir à une action ». The word « une action » is merely a variable.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do-someone-good

Comment: This variable as you say, can take so few values that it's more like a constant...

Comment: By the way, I have less problems with the first part of your question, except the weakness of the Larousse definitions. Why are you still insisting using the Larousse and not the Robert or the TLFi ?

Comment: Lol ahh!!! I understand what you said about the “constant” thing.  Thank you @jlliagre !  So the answer to **(Q1)** is just no? And I am using those dictionaries more slowly by slowly each day (I still find them difficult to use) but all I simply wanted to know for **(Q1)** is if **qch** can replace **qn** in *« réussir à **qn** »*. But the answer is no, right?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse à une personne, oui, par exemple si c'est un livre avec des conseils pour maigrir et que ça marche. Un livre qui réussit à une bibliothèque, c'est un peu tiré par les cheveux. Ça voudrait dire que la bibliothèque a plus de succès à cause d'un simple livre, pourquoi pas...

Comment: It might but not in all cases. Something like *le tourisme ne réussit pas à cette île* is possible. My point about *réussir à* was about Q2, not Q1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119350/discussion-between-cubbykushi-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

<sup>TLFi à « [réussir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ussir) ».</sup>

Sans adverbe (*ce livre lui a réussi*), *réussir* (à) est synonyme de [*convenir*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenir) (à) [be suitable] ; et généralement quand une chose *convient* à une autre chose, ça signifie « être approprié, adapté à cette chose » alors que quand une chose convient à quelqu'un, ça signifie « être bon pour lui, correspondre à ses goûts », d'où l'idée de favoriser et de l'avantage procuré à mon avis. [Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/reussir) explique que quand une chose *réussit* à quelqu'un ça signifie « avoir (pour lui) d'heureux résultats ». Au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9ussir) on a surtout l'idée d'*avoir une issue (heureuse)*.

Je pense qu'essayer de transposer ça à l'inanimé est plutôt hasardeux parce que c'est très relié à la nature de l'individu pour qui une chose représente un avantage. Couramment si un livre *est utile à*, *convient bien à*, *est adapté à la collection de*, *sert bien la vocation de* ou *enrichit* — *une bibliothèque*, oui à défaut de dire ces choses, par extension de sens ou analogie et de manière pas du tout naturelle à mon avis, un peu en trompe-l'oeil (*réussir à* + infinitif etc.), on peut bien essayer de dire qu'un *livre réussit à une bibliothèque* et voir si la réaction de ses interlocuteurs nous *réussit*...

Une curiosité, mais [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/r%C3%A9ussir/68281) traduit lui-même « il a essayé de les rouler, mais ça ne lui a pas réussi » par « he tried to swindle them but it didn't do him any good » ou « it didn't get him very far ». Autrement les exemples sont traduits par l'idée de *to agree with someone, to suit someone* avec la nourriture, le climat, le statut matrimonial, classés avec ce qui précède dans la catégorie de sens « convenir ».

---

Q1. À mon avis, en prenant de grandes libertés avec la langue, et de manière pas du tout naturelle et avec un sens un peu variable et flou, oui, *le livre réussit à la bibliothèque*. Couramment, non.

Comment: Hello @Zéhontée Bonteuse :) I am a bit confused by your first sentence. It clearly states in your screenshot that one of the definitions is *[Sans adv.] Apporter de bons résultats; **être bénéfique***.

Comment: @Noybwbh Indeed, it does. I'm trying (real hard) to reassess what this means using its synonym _convenir_ in context. If you look at my last para., the Larousse link there, I'm reassessing the meaning using that too; either to not agree with someone or to not allow him to benefit from the situation. I speculate _to be beneficial_ is not exactly that, except in its most wide and ultimately meaningless fo constructions. The answer is not without flaw, but irrespective of the meaning, saying that a thing _réussit à_ another thing, is plain weird imho.

Comment: @Noybwbh In so many words I'm trying to say it means more _suitable_ than _beneficial_ if you want.

Comment: Oh okay I understand better now. Thank you! :) How would a person say “Something benefits something else.” in French? For example, CubbyKushi gave the example at the beginning (but it’s not there now) “The book benefits the library.”. <= How would you say that in French?

Comment: @Noybwbh Welcome. Take your pick: "Couramment si un livre _est utile à, convient bien à, est adapté à la collection de, sert bien la vocation de_ ou **enrichit** — une bibliothèque". Do you mean belongs to ? How does that book benefit the library ? The verb _enrichir_ is close to "improve by way of quality", so to speak. I mean word for word you can go with _bénéficier_ i.e. _ce livre bénéficie à la bibliothèque_, but for me that's vague and akin to stating the obvious.

Comment: When I say "belongs to", I mean _befits_ I guess.

Answer (score 1):

*Réussir (à) un examen*: using the preposition with this substantive is acceptable but stands as an [exception](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=r%C3%A9ussir&id=2168) (because technically the person attending the exam is not the person doing the examination; rather it is the person achieving a favourable result at the exam) to standard usage nowadays. It just showcases the usage with this verb, moving away from intransitive or indirect constructions in favour of the direct object complement with nouns (*réussir un examen*). So you would not want to use *réussir à* because *réussir* + direct object noun is simply very typical since the 19th century, and infinitely more so that with the preposition at this point in time. LBU14 (L*e bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, 14<sup>e</sup>, éd. Duculot, §907, 287 a 8, 774 e 3, 1123 b 3) considers the following examples wouldn't even work anymore nowadays:

> En général, elle réussissait À tout ce qu'elle entreprenait (STENDHAL,
> Chartr., VI). — Vous avez mille fois plus d'esprit qu'il n'en faut
> pour réussir À ce projet (BALZAC, cit. Trésor).

It also refers to another example from the TLFi which wouldn't work and which confuses Châteaubriand with [Voltaire's](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Voltaire_-_%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_Garnier_tome23.djvu/366):

[image]

The verb uses the preposition *à* to introduce the infinitive verb, but no longer to introduce the complement, except with *examen* and the like; the TLFi entry doesn't contain any information about this detail. Yet the standard usage is transitive:

[image]

Typically with the inanimate, the verb is intransitive:

[image]

Finally, for the sake of completeness, *réussir à ce que* + conjugated verb (standing together for something like the equivalent of *à [pronoun] (faire)* + the infinitive verb) is possible but undocumented and is seemingly understood by analogy with the *réussir à qqch* construction (LBU): « Il pouvait [...] réussir À CE Qu'elle lui permit de la voir quelquefois » (Proust, *Recherche*, in the LBU14 §1123).

---

Considering all of this I would therefore use:

> La compilation a réussi | échoué / est réussie | un échec.
>  Le
> compilateur n'a pas réussi à compiler.
> Il y a eu une erreur lors de la compilation.
> Le compilateur n'a pas réussi la compilation. [based on the *quelqu'un réussit quelque chose* prototype]

---

Q2. Using the preposition *à* with something else than with an *examen*-related substantive or for introducing an infinitive verb, is not standard today. Nevertheless, using it is not impossible/necessarily incorrect. That being said, usually when there is an inanimate subject, the verb is intransitive. Saying that the compiler succeeded at compiling is a complicated way of saying the compiling was a success because what else than compiling does a compiler do? So alternative ways of expressing this have been provided.

Comment: Both answers are soooooooooooo very detailed thank you ever so much for helping me @Zéhobtée Bobteuse !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Q1: No, this possibility is not found in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ussir) and it does not sound idiomatic.

- <s>Les engrais ont réussi à ce champ.</s>
- Les vitamines ont réussi à ce malade.

Q2: No, except for person-like entities and if the infinitive is used, but then the meaning is somewhat different (parvenir à).

- [ref. 2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=djy5BY6ls8MC&pg=PA38&dq=%22a+r%C3%A9ussi+%C3%A0%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl8Pavk9HuAhUNuRoKHfaMCocQ6AEwC3oECDIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20r%C3%A9ussi%20%C3%A0%22&f=false) Ce profil est caractéristique d'une organisation qui a réussi **à s'adapter** aux exigences de son environnement de façon correcte.

For this second sentence, where "qch" is the subject, you  don't use the preposition "à", which gives you the desired meaning.

Le compilateur a réussit la compilation du code. **or** Le compilateur a réussit à compiler le code.
*The compiler succeeded in the compilation of the code.*

Comment: "ONT" réussi et non pas "ON" réussi.

Comment: @BernardMassé Thanks